# Can't call javascript client method in signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

The following code works fine in IIS Express, but failed in IIS10.

The weird thing is serverside method can successfully be invoked, however clientside method can't.

#### JavaScript

```
var hub = $.connection.liveRoomHub;
hub.client.addMessageToPage = function(data){
    debugger;//here, this method never gets invoked
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
};
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function() {
        hub.server.join('room1')
        .done(function(){
            debugger; //code can run into here
            hub.server.sendMessage('user','test','room1');
        })
    });
```

#### C#

```
public class LiveRoomHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public async Task SendMessage(string name, string message, string roomName)
    {
        await Clients.Group(roomName)
            .addMessageToPage(new
            {
                Name = name,
                Message = message
            });
        Logger.Info($"{name}send msg：{message}in room:{roomName}，");//logged
    }

    public async Task Join(string roomName)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
        Logger.Info($"{Context.ConnectionId} enter room: {roomName}");//logged
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone knows how to close this question.

Comment: Jack, you should be able to accept your own answer by now. However, could you put an example of the "failure" into the question, above?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Michael, but I can't provide more additional info about how the above code fails. The js code just fails silently: client hub method not execute, no exception nor warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, problem solved.

I'm using aspnetboilerplate, and `abp.signalr.js` automatically calls the hub connection before my JavaScript code is loaded.

Obviously, at that time, my `hub.client.addMessageToPage` isn't registered yet.

That's the common `Connection started before subscriptions are added` error.